# Theorems with dash between numbers

Tags: numbering, theorems

I want to make theorems that look like this, but with better spacing:

***1-1 Theorem*** **(** ***Theorem name*** **)** *Statement of the theorem.*

Here is what I currently have:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheoremstyle{theorem}
{1.5em} % Space above
{} % Space below
{\itshape} % Body font
{}  % Indent amount
% Indent amount: empty = no indent; \parindent = normal paragraph indent
{\bfseries\itshape} % Theorem head font
{} % Punctuation after theorem head
{1em} % Space after theorem head
% Space after theorem head: { } = normal interword space; \newline = line break
{\thmnumber{#2}\thmname{\hspace{1em}#1}\thmnote{ \textup({#3}\textup)}}
% Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning `normal`)

\theoremstyle{theorem}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}

\begin{thm}[Theorem name] Statement of the theorem.
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

I just don't know how to change the dot to a dash.

Comment: `\renewcommand{\thethm}{\thesection--\arabic{thm}}` after the `\newtheorem` statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment you can simply use this:

```
\newtheoremstyle{theorem}
{1.5em} % Space above
{} % Space below
{\itshape} % Body font
{}  % Indent amount
% Indent amount: empty = no indent; \parindent = normal paragraph indent
{\bfseries\itshape} % Theorem head font
{} % Punctuation after theorem head
{1em} % Space after theorem head
% Space after theorem head: { } = normal interword space; \newline = line break
{\thmnumber{#2}\thmname{\hspace{1em}#1}\thmnote{ \textup({#3}\textup)}}
% Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning `normal`)

\theoremstyle{theorem}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\renewcommand{\thethm}{\thesection\ --\ \arabic{thm}}
```

This would create something like this:

[image]

The important part is this:

```
\renewcommand{\thethm}{\thesection\ --\ \arabic{thm}}
```

There you can also remove the spaces I put there:

```
\renewcommand{\thethm}{\thesection--\arabic{thm}}
```

[image]

Or create something completely different:

```
\renewcommand{\thethm}{\thesection\ $\cdot$ \Roman{thm}}
```

[image]